# How to send Lightblue Bean sensor values to iOS app without using bean iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, ibeacon, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to make an iOS swift app such that the app displays the current sensor values (accelerometer, temp) that the Lightblue Bean is getting over Bluetooth.

However I am getting confused by how to get the specific sensor values. I am able to run the sample iOS application for ibeacon, so I know the bean is connecting with the iOS app. From what I've gathered, an ibeacon only tells you its UUID and doesn't tell you more data. Is there a way for ibeacon to send sensor values to the iOS app? There is documentation for the bean that provides each of the sensor's major and minor UUIDs but I don't know how to use that information in my app to display those sensor values.

Comment: First, why not use the SDK? But if you don't then you need to use CBCentralManager to discover and connect to the bean. You can then discover the characteristics (these are the UUIDs, there aren't major and minor values, just a UUID value) and issue read requests for those characteristics.  This is different to ibeacon mode which would be accessed with core location

Comment: I'm trying to later use the code for a different device (not the bean) so I want to make it adaptable across different devices. So you're saying that in order for me to get these sensor readings from the bean I can't use ibeacon? I just call a method that reads characteristics?

Comment: That's right. An ibeacon just broadcasts some numbers. You need to use CoreBluetooth to connect to the peripheral and read the characteristic values

Comment: I figured that I should be reading the values in func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) , but I can't figure out how to actually get the values that I want. Like I don't know how to convert it so that I get meaningful data? I have this

Comment: let dataBytes = characteristic.value
        print(dataBytes)
        var dataArray = [Int16](count: dataBytes!.length, repeatedValue: 0)
        print(dataArray)   
but dataArray is just [] or [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Your second statement creates an array with sixteen 0s in it, so no surprise. `characteristic.value` should contains the bytes of the value stored in an NSData instancd, how you interpret it depends on the characteristic in question. Which characteristic are you reading?

Comment: The thing is I don't know what characteristics I'm reading.... I'm just trying to print out characteristic.description and I'm getting stuff like <CBService: 0x134650ab0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = A495FF20-C5B1-4B44-B512-1370F02D74DE> . Is there a way to figure out what this characteristic is? Like is this something that lets me find specific sensor readings?

Comment: That is the service. You need to call discoverCharacteristics:forService on the peripheral to get the characteristics. You said you had the documentation of characteristics. I believe with the Bean you need to send specific serial commands on the serial port characteristics to read the accelerometers etc. that is why it is easier to use their SDK framework

Comment: That's what I suspected -- I looked in the bean iOS SDK and they are using gatt serial transport to send messages to get the sensor readings. Looks like I may have to temporarily use their SDK since I don't understand the logic behind what they are doing. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this working without?

Comment: Yes I used the core Bluetooth library and implemented the methods. Check out this link for an example that I modeled my project from: https://github.com/0x7fffffff/Core-Bluetooth-Transfer-Demo/blob/master/Bluetooth/BTLECentralViewController.swift